# How to get position of key in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

If a key is present in a dictionary, I want to know what position the key is in i.e the numerical index. For example :

if the dictionary consists of :

```
{'test':{1,3},'test2':{2},'test3':{2,3}}

if 'test' in dictionary:
   print(the index of that key)
```

The output would be 0 for example. (The output would be 2 for 'test3'...)

I'm using a dictionary at the moment, I'm guessing I'd have to use an ordered `dict` to do this, but how can I do it using an ordered `dict` ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 21):

As of Python 3.6, dictionaries now [preserves the insertion order](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html).  So using Python 3.6+, you could get the index by converting the `dict_keys` to a list.

```
dictionary = {'test':{1,3}, 'test2':{2}, 'test3':{2,3}}

if 'test' in dictionary:
   print(list(dictionary).index('test'))
```

As another example, the following demonstrates how to find the index for a few keys of interest.

```
key_list = list(dictionary)
keys_of_interest = ['test2', 'test3']

for key in keys_of_interest:
    print('key: {}, index: {}'.format(key, key_list.index(key)))
```

The output from this would be

```
key: test2, index: 1
key: test3, index: 2
```

Answer (score 13):

For Python <3.6, you cannot do this because dictionaries in Python have no order to them, so items don't have an index. You could use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` library instead though, and pass it a tuple of tuples:

```
>>> import collections
>>> d = collections.OrderedDict((('test',{1,3}),('test2',{2}),('test3',{2,3})))
>>> d.keys().index('test3') # Replace with list(d.keys()).index("test3") for Python 3
2
```

Comment: That does not work exactly like that in Python 3, since `OrderedDict.keys` returns an instance of `odict_keys` there and not a list. I guess, one has to cast that into a tuple or a list first in Python 3: `tuple(d.keys()).index('test3')`

Comment: Thanks @Callidior, I've changed my code to work with Python 3 as well.

Comment: This only applies for Python <3.6.  For Python 3.6+, dictionaries now preserve insertion order.  See this [email from the Python-Dev mailing list](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html) for discussion and an example.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell Oh, that's a great new feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can just build an index :

```
ind= {k:i for i,k in enumerate(dictionary.keys())}
```

then `ind['test3']` will be 2, with O(1) access time.

This is robust while keys are fixed.  If you add/remove keys, you have to rebuild the index.

Answer (score 3):

You can just convert dict.keys() to a list and then index the list

```
keys = list(dictionary.keys())
index = keys.index("test")
```

indexing values that are not in the list will result in ValueError

```
keys.index("test5")
ValueError: "test5" is not in list
```

Answer (score 2):

With python 3.6 or later, with dicts preserving insertion order, then you can do it in one line, with it returning 'None' if the key isn't in the dictionary:

```
key_index = list(my_dictionary).index(the_key) if the_key in my_dictionary else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, such a thing is not possible because of how dictionaries are constructed in python.  These data structures are inherently *unordered*.

To get the functionallity you want you must use a different data structure, such as [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
 def list_has_dict_by_key(_lst: list[dict], _key: any):
        fn = lambda lst, key: [i for i, d in enumerate(lst) if key in d.keys()] or [-1]
        return fn(_lst, _key).pop
```