# Compare dict keys with respect to order (less, greater, equal)

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have a following dict: `some_dict = {"START": "something", "MAIN": "something", "END": "something"}`

How to compare its keys like

```
for key in some_dict.keys():
    if key < "MAIN":
        print(f"Key {key} appears before 'MAIN'")
    elif key > "MAIN":
        print(f"Key {key} appears after 'MAIN'")
```

I understand that keys of `dict` are just `str` and by default comparisons like `key < "MAIN"` will be performed with respect to rules for `str`, but is there probably a special `dict` type that uses its special key type that allows order comparison?

### UPD: My approach

Thanks to [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi), [@PoneyUHC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19033618/poneyuhc), [@Achille G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10687907/achille-g) for approach with `list.index(elem)` but this requires changes in comparison itself.

What I meant was a new class like `dict`, that supports comparison for its keys, so

```
from typing import List, TypeVar

KT = TypeVar('KT')
VT = TypeVar('VT')


def def_compareable_keyclass(nobj, index):
    class CK(type(nobj)):
        def __init__(self, some_obj) -> None:
            type(nobj).__init__(some_obj)
            self.order_based_comparison_index = index

        def __lt__(self, other) -> bool:
            return self.order_based_comparison_index < other.order_based_comparison_index

        def __le__(self, other) -> bool:
            return self.order_based_comparison_index <= other.order_based_comparison_index

        def __gt__(self, other) -> bool:
            return self.order_based_comparison_index > other.order_based_comparison_index

        def __ge__(self, other) -> bool:
            return self.order_based_comparison_index >= other.order_based_comparison_index

        def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
            return self.order_based_comparison_index == other.order_based_comparison_index

        def __ne__(self, other) -> bool:
            return self.order_based_comparison_index != other.order_based_comparison_index

    return CK


class not_dict(dict[KT, VT]):
    def keys(self) -> List[KT]:
        s_keys = super().keys()
        r_keys: List[KT] = []
        for i, key in enumerate(s_keys):
            r_keys.append(def_compareable_keyclass(key, i)(key))
        return r_keys
```

It works:

```
some_dict = not_dict({"START": "something", "MAIN": "something", "END": "something"})

pivot = some_dict.keys()[1]

for key in some_dict.keys():
    if key < pivot:
        print(f"Key '{key}' appears before '{pivot}'")
    elif key > pivot:
        print(f"Key '{key}' appears after '{pivot}'")
    elif key == pivot:
        print(f"Key '{key}' is '{pivot}'")
```

Output:

```
Key 'START' appears before 'MAIN'
Key 'MAIN' is 'MAIN'
Key 'END' appears after 'MAIN'
```

Comment: Is `key < "MAIN"` supposed to get the order from the *words* `START`, `MAIN`, `END` or from the *position* of keys in the dict?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi from position

Comment: I think fundamentally you need to know [How to get position of key in a dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090175/how-to-get-position-of-key-in-a-dictionary-in-python). Comparisons based on these positions is straightforward then.

Comment: dict keys are ordered in their insert order and if you want to do code like that you probably need to implement your own dict and probably also new class type for key and do plenty of operator overloading.  From syntax point of view, not adviced.

Comment: Easier way would be to do second dictionary that stores the position of the key in your main dict  as value and key as a key  and then do a lookup against that ..

Comment: Please do not [edit] answers into the question. If you have your own answer and want to share it, post it as an actual answer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it is not an answer, it is an example approach. I think one can rewrite my example in a way better, more pythonic way.

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of the iteration order of dictionaries:

```
found_main = False
for key in some_dict:
    if key == "MAIN":
        found_main = True
    elif found_main:
        print(f"Key {key} appears after 'MAIN'")
    else
        print(f"Key {key} appears before 'MAIN'")
```

If you want to be able to tell the order without looping over `some_dict`, you could do something like this:

```
def keys_before(dictionary, pivot_key):
    keys = set()
    for key in dictionary:
        if key == pivot_key:
            break
        keys.add(key)
    return keys

start_keys = keys_before(some_dict, 'MAIN')
```

Then instead of `key < 'MAIN'`, use `key in start_keys` and instead of `key > 'MAIN'` use `key != 'MAIN' and key not in start_keys`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6), dictionary are ordered relatively to their insertion.
If you get the keys from a dict, they will respect this order.
Then thanks to the `index` function, you can check ordering.

```py
key = 'some_key'
l = list(d.keys())
if l.index(key) < l.index('MAIN')
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dict` type does not offer a simple way to get the index of a key/item. However, a single pass is sufficient to build a second `dict` that provides this information:

```
data = {"START": "something", "MAIN": "something", "END": "something"}

# enumerate the keys in-order to get the index for each key ...
# ... and store that in a dict for fast lookup
key_index = {key: index for index, key in enumerate(data)}

for key in data:
    if key_index[key] < key_index["MAIN"]:
        print(f"Key {key} appears before 'MAIN'")
    elif key_index[key] > key_index["MAIN"]:
        print(f"Key {key} appears after 'MAIN'")
```

This is efficient even for large data as creating the `key_order` only needs a single additional pass over data. Afterwards, getting the index of a key benefits from the fast, direct lookup of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such dictionaries exists.
My workaround would be to create a list out of your dictionary's keys then compare the indexes.

```
some_dict = {"START": "something", "MAIN": "something", "END": "something"}

key_order = list(some_dict.keys())

for key in some_dict.keys():
    if key_order.index(key) < key_order.index("MAIN"):
        print(f"Key {key} appears before 'MAIN'")
    elif key_order.index(key) > key_order.index("MAIN"):
        print(f"Key {key} appears after 'MAIN'")
```

Comment: This has quadratic time complexity, if `len(some_dict)` is twice as large, this code takes 4 times as long to run. Don't use this for large dictionaries.

Comment: Indeed, upon testing this solution takes `0.09`s for a 1000 entries dictionaries vs `0.0003` with @Jasmijn solution